# FloatingActionButton and Admob ad loading

Tags: android, admob, floating-action-button

I have an activity that shows an ad which also has Floating Action Button.

I have setup like this:

- By Default adView is set to hidden (gone)
- It starts loading in Activity's onCreate
- After it is loaded it is set to Visible
- Which moves the FAB up to make room for the adView

Is this behavior good? In the best practices, (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877?hl=en) I didn't found the answer to this question.

When user is offline, I don't want user to see the blank space with the fab above it! It looks ugly.

Comment: You can assign the background color of adView to the same which your activity has, so it won't look like an explicit empty space will just give a look of uplifted fab. Another thing.

Comment: I have a default white background. But, Uplifted fab looks very very ugly! Seriously!

Comment: yes it will :D better move adView to some other position.!

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder Most (almost all) of my activities are having a floating action button..

Comment: post a screenshot of layout we might suggest a better location or adjustment of views according to your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with an idea of providing a different background color and a small text line (*tag line or anything*).

So that it is not just the blank background, it looks a bit good with the text. And that space will be filled when ad finishes loading.